# Easiest way to create a PDF that has a table with images? (HTML/JS)

Tags: javascript, html

I've done a ton of reading and I can't find a simple way to generate a PDF that has a table with images in it.

The closest thing I found is [some abomination](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable) with a `jsPDF` plugin called `jsPDF-AutoTable` that uses `didDrawCell` to render a base64 blob of the image...

Also, there's the save a canvas as an image in a PDF, but that is also not good.

There has to be an easier way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Well for one, you can use Puppeteer. Another is using a package called wkhtmltopdf.
Both of these would require to recreate the page structure again. You can try any of the methods specified   [here](https://blog.risingstack.com/pdf-from-html-node-js-puppeteer/)

Comment: Since this is a recommendation don't you think it would be best posted as a comment and not a solution since this doesn't provide enough information about your recommendations or offer a working demo...